# Code works in fiddle, but not on webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Have tried and tested code in fiddle, the aim is to hide second column when there is a 1 in the dropdown at the top, this works on fiddle, but nothing changes on webpage. Any ideas.

Testing webpage is on a live site, located here: http://www.specialfinance.co.uk/introducers/submit-an-enquiry/secured-loans2.html

Comment: fiddle is located here: http://jsfiddle.net/FFJbY/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jQuery code is executing before the elements are in the DOM. Wrap it inside a [DOM Ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) handler to fix that:

```
$(function() {
    //your code here
    $("#selectList").change(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == "1") {
           $(".showMe").hide();
        }
        else {
            $(".showMe").show();
        }
    });
});
```

Your fiddle has an onLoad wrapper (top-left of the page) which automatically wraps your code inside an `window.onload` function.

`window.onload` works too but it takes considerably longer than a DOM ready handler to kick in when you have a large page with images and other resources.

Answer (score 0):

Enclose your jquery in a `document.ready()` handler, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#selectList").change(function() {
       if ($(this).val() == "1") {
          $(".showMe").hide();
       }
       else {
           $(".showMe").show();
       }
   });
});
```