# javascript not working locally but works in jsfiddle

Tags: javascript

I have very simple code

html

```
<div id="ball" class="ball"></div>
```

css

```
#ball{
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background: #0f0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 150px;
    left: 350px;
}
```

javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('ball').style.backgroundColor="red";
</script>
```

I tried this code in jsfiddle and it works but why this is not working locally? I tried changing  to  ,  but I've no idea why this is not working. It's showing the error:

> TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

Comment: I know I can do it with jquery very easily but wanted to know with javascript... and I'm first to javascript.

Comment: Most likely you're executing the script before the element exists.

Comment: script is in head tag and html is in body tag . so how to do?

Comment: also see [Code works in fiddle, but not on webpage](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15385482/218196)

Comment: Show your full HTML page code.

Comment: full code in the page is same as in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, your initialization order is messed up. You can [use `window.onload`](http://roberthahn.ca/articles/2007/02/02/how-to-use-window-onload-the-right-way/) to fix it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById('ball').style.backgroundColor="red";
    };
</script>
```

Note also that you can only have one `onload` trigger function. [Here are some ideas](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3724571) on how to support multiple trigger functions. The easiest, is of course, to just use [JQuery's ready function](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Another way is to put the <script> tag into the body after the DOM element(s) that it depends on. This is often encouraged for performance reasons, but it tends to make things less readable.

The reason as to why <script> tags in the head are executed in sequence (instead of delaying execution until after the DOM has loaded) is: Performance. For example, you sometimes might want to start asynchronous requests before the document has finished loading. If you are not concerned about performance, it's safer to execute them "onload".

Ultimately, there are a lot of considerations to be made when placing your <script> tag. If you want to learn more, [this](http://javascript.about.com/od/hintsandtips/a/bestplace.htm) might be a good starting point.

About the second part of your question: The reason as to why it works in JSFiddle is that, by default, it executes scripts onload. You can reproduce the bug on JSfiddle by choosing "no wrap - in head": http://jsfiddle.net/aDuwg/.

Comment: thanks. its working. so it means whatever I code in js should be within onload?

Comment: @C-Link No, just what needs to be load first.

Comment: @C-Link I added an explanation to answer your question.

Comment: @C-Link: The only rule is that the element you are trying to access has to exist. There are multiple ways to achieve that, this is one of them.

Comment: *"The reason as to why `<script>` tags in the head are not executed onload by default is because you sometimes might want to start some asynchronous requests before the document has finished loaded"* That's not the reason. The reason is that the content of a `script` element is evaluated when the element is encountered during the parsing process.

Comment: You can include the script tag in the body of HTML after all of your elements and it should work there too. In fact, many people recommend putting all your script tags at the bottom of the HTML document, rather than the top.

Comment: @FelixKling but why are they evaluated in that sequence? I don't think that my answer is the ultimate answer to that question, but I think it describes a common use-case. I tweaked it a bit.

Comment: @JimPedid I like your response. I added a sentence on that as well. I hope, you don't mind?

Comment: Keep in mind that Ajax didn't exist when JavaScript was developed. I believe that the decision was made because it felt natural: Why should a `<script>` be treated than an other element? Anyways, I wasn't there, I cannot tell what the ultimate reason was. All I know is that documents are processed from top to button, so it makes sense that every element is processed in order.