# How can I get my JavaScript to work on website? (Current code is working on Fiddle just not on website)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create a Character Counter for a Custom Field on a Product Page.  I am trying to use the following JavaScript and HTML code to achieve such a function:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="fields-group-1">    

    <table class="fields_table  product-custom-text-wrapper" cellspacing="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="label"><label class=" product-custom-text-label" for="custom_text">Custom Text</label></td>
                <td class="value">
                <input type="text" class="field product-custom-text" name="custom_text" value="" placeholder="Enter Custom Text ..." maxlength="16" type="text" pattern="mandatory" mandatory="no"  />
                    <span class="validation-message is-valid-1"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>


</div>

<span id="character_count"></span> //This is where I am attempting to output the Character Count.
```

**JavaScript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$('.product-custom-text').keyup(updateCount);
$('.product-custom-text').keydown(updateCount);

function updateCount() {
    var cs = $(this).val().length;
    $('#character_count').text(cs);
}
</script>
```

When running this within the Fiddle program, I can generate the Character Counter. However, when I place the above code into the website, the Character Counter does not seem to work.  I have checked the Source Code and all of the coding is there.

I can see that someone else has experienced a similar issue to myself, as per th question at: [Code works in fiddle, but not on webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15385482/code-works-in-fiddle-but-not-on-webpage).  As a newbie to JavaScript, I am not 100% sure of a suitable fix.

Is anyone able to point me in the right direction as to the relevant changes I would need to make in order for my above coding to work?

Comment: Can you please post a link to your fiddle.

Comment: Are you importing jQuery to your page? Also try wrapping your first two lines inside `$(document).ready(function(){})`

Comment: Wrap your JavaScript in `$(document).ready(function() { })`

Comment: You are using jquery as well. JSFIddle has it innately. However when you are including your script inside your html you also have to add jquery to your scripts tags and wrap your code in  `$(document).ready(function(){})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your binding like below:

```
jQuery(document).on('keyup', '.product-custom-text', updateCount);
jQuery(document).on('keydown', '.product-custom-text', updateCount);
```

This binding does not require to be inside `$( document ).ready(function() {` function, because it will work for available `DOM` elements

You need to use document.ready for keyup event. Before this moment DOM elements you're referring in jQuery selectors aren't available.

```js
jQuery(document).on('keyup', '.product-custom-text', updateCount);
jQuery(document).on('keydown', '.product-custom-text', updateCount);

function updateCount() {
    var cs = $(this).val().length;
    jQuery('#character_count').text(cs);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fields-group-1">    

    <table class="fields_table  product-custom-text-wrapper" cellspacing="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="label"><label class=" product-custom-text-label" for="custom_text">Custom Text</label></td>
                <td class="value">
                <input type="text" class="field product-custom-text" name="custom_text" value="" placeholder="Enter Custom Text ..." maxlength="16" type="text" pattern="mandatory" mandatory="no"  />
                    <span class="validation-message is-valid-1"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>


</div>

<span id="character_count"></span>
```

**Edit:** As per discussion, In wordpress sites, there might be chances of having `$` confliction, so try using `jQuery` insted of `$`. Updated answer!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I have tried this but to no success.  Regarding `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`, does it matter whether I enqueue this via the `functions.php` file or hard code it directly into the page's template page?

Comment: @Craig you have to include `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jque‌​ry.min.js"></script>` on your page, where you are using jquery code to make it work

Comment: Do not enqueue this via the functions.php, just copy and paste to include jquery script on that page

Comment: Unfortunately, I copied your suggested code as you placed here but to no success.

Comment: Ok, can you please check your browser console and put the javascript error here.

Comment: The only errors I have are:  `JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1 and Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function at (index):1452 (anonymous) @ (index):1452`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143730/discussion-between-mahesh-singh-chouhan-and-craig).

Comment: Many apologies for contacting you again.  The advised code conflicts with the Basket feature and prevents products from being shown.  Any ideas on why this is?  This is the code `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
jQuery(document).on('keyup', '.product-custom-text', updateCount);
jQuery(document).on('keydown', '.product-custom-text', updateCount);

function updateCount() {
    var cs = $(this).val().length;
    jQuery('#character_count').text(cs);
}
</script>

<span id="character_count"></span>`

Comment: Hey @Craig, please check the discussion chat

Answer (score 0):

You are using jQuery functions, but are you importing jQuery to use it in your site? Also, your function should be wrapped in a jQuery docready function.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    //your code
});
```

It works in the Fiddle, because jsFiddle includes jQuery for you. In your build you have to import it.

Answer (score 0):

As you pointed out it's wordpress: no need to include the jquery source. WP enqueues it by default (though other plugins can remove that)

Wrap your jquery code inside $.ready.

For wordpress: it forces no-conflict mode, and therefor for all jquery code you must use `jQuery` instead of the `$` alias, OR use the following as the `$.ready` wrapper: `jQuery(function($){  // your code with $ stuff  });`